# What does `+option` mean in a bash command?

Tags: bash, getopt

I have never seen some special bash format before.
[special bash command :foo -a -c +b](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html)

```
 foo -a -c +b
```

`foo` is a bash command ,`a` and `c` are `foo`'s options.
For the above command ,what does `+b` mean here?

To disable an option within a script.

`foo` command has the `b` option ,or say,there is a `b` behavior in `foo` command,

`foo -a -c +b` is to invoke `ac` behavior and disable `b` behavior.

Why not just run with :

```
foo -a -c
```

Comment: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html

Comment: Since `foo` handles the options, it can choose to interpret `+` however it wants. The Bash builtin `getopts` only understands single letter options with `-`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html), for bash options:

- `-option` enables an option that defaults to disabled
- `+option` disables an option that defaults to enabled

So it would make sense that other programs would follow the same method of enabling and disabling options.

A bash example given is:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  set -o verbose
  # Command echoing on.
  command
  ...
  command

  set +o verbose
  # Command echoing off.
  command
  # Not echoed.


  set -v
  # Command echoing on.
  command
  ...
  command

  set +v
  # Command echoing off.
  command

  exit 0
```